# Fatal error: in wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php EC2 Bitnami

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, updates, php-8

I’ve this instance on **AWS EC2** on a **Bitnami** stack. Today I received this error, I had never seen anything like it and before making any changes I would like to know some consideration before. Before restoring I would like to know if I can solve it from the files.

```
@include base64_decode("L29wdC9iaXRuYW1pL3dvcmRwcmVzcy93cC1pbmNsdWRlcy9pbWFnZXMvd3BpY29ucy0zeC5wbmc=");
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function absint() in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php:2162 Stack trace: #0 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php(2004): wpdb->parse_db_host() #1 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php(773): wpdb->db_connect() #2 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php(582): wpdb->__construct() #3 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-settings.php(124): require_wp_db() #4 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php(104): require_once('...') #5 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...') #6 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('...') #7 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/index.php(1): require('...') #8 {main} thrown in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2162

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_die() in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php:239 Stack trace: #0 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(154): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template() #1 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(58): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template() #2 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #3 {main} thrown in /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 239
```

[image]

1. I have disabled all plugins.
2. I have deactivated the used theme and the problem continues.
3. I have rebooted the EC2 instance from the AWS console.

Comment: Looks like you've been hacked